# how to insert null value in sqlite3 with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I created a table in sqlite3, following is the structure:

```
cid     name                    type    notnull         pk
0   wheelId                 INTEGER 1       1
1   wheelName           VARCHAR 1       0
2   paraDiam            INTEGER 0       0
3   paraWidth           FLOAT   0       0
4   paraEt                  FLOAT   0       0
5   paraHole            INTEGER 0       0
6   factParaHole            INTEGER 0       0
7   paraCenterhole          FLOAT   0       0
8   wheelColorName          VARCHAR 0       0
9   wheelColorNameShow  TEXT    0       0
10  paraWeight          FLOAT   0       0
11  vpPrice                 INTEGER 0       0
12  ntStock                 INTEGER 0       0
13  wheelURL            VARCHAR 0       0
14  wheelImg            VARCHAR 0       0
15  wheelRank           INTEGER 0       0
```

and now, I use python to insert a record into the table, and I only want to insert the column value 'wheelName', 'wheelImg' and keep the other columns null, (the first one is `wheelId`, and I hope it can increment by itself automatically).

I used almost every method I can find on the website:

1. `cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO WHEELS (wheelName,wheelImg) VALUES (%s,%s)""" ,
                       (WHEELNAME,WHEELIMG))`

   Python throws `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`
2. ```
   cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO WHEELS(WHEELID,WHEELNAME, PARADIAM, PARAWIDTH, PARAET,PARAHOLE,FACTPARAHOLE,
                           PARACENTERHOLE,WHEELCOLORNAME,WHEELCOLORNAMESHOW,PARAWEIGHT,VPPRICE,NTSTOCK,
                           WHEELURL,WHEELIMG,WHEELRANK)

                  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""" ,
                  (WHEELID, WHEELNAME, PARADIAM, PARAWIDTH, PARAET,PARAHOLE,FACTPARAHOLE,
                   PARACENTERHOLE,WHEELCOLORNAME,WHEELCOLORNAMESHOW,PARAWEIGHT,VPPRICE,NTSTOCK,
                   WHEELURL,WHEELIMG,WHEELRANK))
   ```

where I set the other values to `None`
like:

```
PARADIAM = None
PARAWIDTH = None
PARAET = None
PARAHOLE = None
```

and python again throws `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqlite3` adapter uses `?` for SQL parameters, not `%s`:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO WHEELS (wheelName,wheelImg) VALUES (?, ?)", (WHEELNAME,WHEELIMG))
```

Your schema also restricts the `wheelColorNameShow`:

```
"wheelColorNameShow" TEXT check(typeof("wheelColorNameShow") = 'text')
```

which means it can no longer be NULL. You *have* to include a value for that column too:

```
cursor.execute('insert into wheels (wheelName,wheelImg,wheelColorNameShow) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', ('test', 'test', 'test'))
```

succeeds.

Comment: cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO WHEELS
                       VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""" ,
                        (WHEELID, WHEELNAME, PARADIAM, PARAWIDTH, PARAET,PARAHOLE,FACTPARAHOLE,
                        PARACENTERHOLE,WHEELCOLORNAME,WHEELCOLORNAMESHOW,PARAWEIGHT,VPPRICE,NTSTOCK,
                        WHEELURL,WHEELIMG,WHEELRANK))                  sqlite3.IntegrityError: constraint failed

Comment: make sure you surround strings being inserted with single quotes

Comment: sqlite3.IntegrityError: constraint failed

Comment: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO WHEELS (wheelName,wheelImg) VALUES (?, ?)", ("test","test"))                           sqlite3.IntegrityError: constraint failed

Comment: @staryin: SQLLite does not think your primary key column can be omitted, it appears.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran: No, that's the task of the database, that is what we use sql parameters *for*.

Comment: @staryin: are there any foreign keys in the table? See http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html for auto-incrementation and primary keys rules.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters : cursor.execute("INSERT INTO WHEELS (wheelId, wheelName,wheelImg) VALUES (?,?, ?)", (1, 'test','test'))                 also told me : sqlite3.IntegrityError: constraint failed

Comment: @staryin: You need to share the full `CREATE TABLE` statement then; you have another constraint in there; I cannot guess what that could be from here.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters : CREATE TABLE "wheels" ("wheelId" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "wheelName" VARCHAR NOT NULL , "paraDiam" INTEGER, "paraWidth" FLOAT, "paraEt" FLOAT, "paraHole" INTEGER, "factParaHole" INTEGER, "paraCenterhole" FLOAT, "wheelColorName" VARCHAR, "wheelColorNameShow" TEXT check(typeof("wheelColorNameShow") = 'text') , "paraWeight" FLOAT, "vpPrice" INTEGER, "ntStock" INTEGER, "wheelURL" VARCHAR, "wheelImg" VARCHAR, "wheelRank" INTEGER)